# nsupdate and bind

Tags: bind

I'm updating my zone configuration using nsupdate. My question is - does bind need to be restarted for update to take place?

Answer (score 1):

I just tried adding a cname on a test system and didn't need to restart bind for the cname to become usable.

Answer (score 1):

it should not be need it - this is what the man pages says

> Zones that are under dynamic control via nsupdate or a DHCP server should not be edited by hand. Manual edits could conflict with dynamic updates and cause data to be lost.

also you can run the nsupdate with -d to debug the request/response.